# Specify only uncertainty with exponent notation using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I use the `siunitx` package to format numbers and units. Let's say I have a lab measurement where the value is of a "regular" order of magnitude, but the uncertainty is really small. For example: `n = 1.000269 +- 0.000009`.
Both I and my lab instructor think that representing the error in exponent notation is more elegant: `n = 1.000269 +- 9e-6`. However, I couldn't achieve this with `siunitx`. Doing `\num{1.000269(9e-6)}` gives an error, and doing `\num{1.000269(9)}` gives me the decimal representation.

Is there a way to write a number with small uncertainty in exponent notation like I want? Or do I have to fall back to writing the measurement using pure latex, which means I lose nice features of `siunitx` like group separation?

A MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    group-separator = {,},
    group-digits=integer,
    uncertainty-mode=separate
}

\begin{document}
Currently with \verb|siunitx| (Decimal form. Not ideal for an uncertainty of order \(\sim 10^{-6}\)):
\[ n = \num{1.000269(0.000009)} \]
Desired result (Exponent form):
\[ n = 1.000269 \pm 9 \times 10^{-6} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add code to your questions, which a) starts at \documentclass, ends at \end{document}, puts your numbers in between AND compiles AND shows your problem. Thank you